# Error Handling in UFT/QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I've a framework where the methods are called inside an action from Function Libraries. I'm trying to do error handling to avoid errors thrown by code written inside the function Libraries.

Below is my action code:

```
on error resume next
call TestMe()
if err.number Then: msgbox err.description
on error goto 0
```

And here is the function inside function library:

```
Function TestMe()
   x = 1/0
End Function
```

When I execute my test, `on error resume next` doesn't seems to be working as I get an error pop-up for division by zero inside the function TestMe().

How can I get these error handled without moving the code?

Comment: Why would you not expect an error pop-up?  That's how you have it coded.  You return from the call and say "if I have an error show a message".

Comment: This statement works fine! Double-check your code!

Comment: @BrianMStafford -> Error message is thrown inside the function TestMe()

Comment: @GTAVLover Code is similar, It's just error thrown from the function library is not being handled by the `on error resume next` inside the Action.

Comment: @yudi2312 Then add this statement inside the function also! :-)

Comment: @GTAVLover that is what I'm trying to avoid as I don't want all the lines to be executed inside the function. I want to get out from the function in case of any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly with all the time using QTP/UFT never came up against such case. Was quite intriguing as well.
I Found out (or so it seems at first glance) that the scope of `on error resume next` is limited to its level (Library/Action) and couldn't be carried over to either.

You might wanna try something like:

Action Code:

```
Call Test3()
```

Function Library:

```
Function Test1()
      x = 1/0
End Function

Function Test2()
   Call Test1()
   MsgBox "Test2"
End Function

Function Test3()
   On Error Resume next
   Call Test2()
   MsgBox err.Description
End Function
```

The execution using this statement continues until it finds a handler. So you may set up a condition where ever you deem fit.

Another alternative is to use a flag (could be an environment variable) like

```
Environment("Flag") = True
```

Whose condition can be checked directly in action code

Hope this helps. I'll still try to dig up more about this

Comment: I was thinking of creating a method to execute other methods to make sure that all errors are rescued. And I'm not clear about the alternative approach by using a flag. Can you thrown some more light on this?

Comment: I dont know how your code is and so it is difficult to suggest on it. but if your goal is to not use on error statement multiple times then you can do so using the above answer. Mind you it will work only at a level i.e. library file - in the above example you may use on error statement in the Test1() as well and handle it in Test3().

Comment: Flag is nothing but an environment variable. You can set the environment variable as true (while you want to begin execution) and when some condition fails (which can be either in library or action) you can set the environment variable as False, now you need to add a condition under each function you are calling to check for the flag ( so each function is called only if the flag is True) this way if any one function has failed you would come out of it. This explanation is just elementary, you would need script it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below article. This is explaining the same issue in detail

https://sumeetkushwah.com/2014/08/12/implementing-try-catch-functionality-in-qtpuft/

Answer (score -1):

```
on error resume next

call TestMe()

on error goto 0

if err.number Then: msgbox err.description

Function TestMe()

   x = 1/0

End Function
```